# Add WKT to OpenLayers 3 map

Tags: arcgis-server, openlayers, well-known-text

I recently converted from ESRI products, and I am trying to get a grip on adding a vector layer to OL3 from features returned from the server as WKT.

[Here](http://codepen.io/vbahole/pen/vKxeBb) is some example code.

Why I am not seeing a feature in this example?

Note that [this pen](http://codepen.io/vbahole/pen/LZWzpJ) does work and is very similar: .

Comment: Are your coordinates correct? Where should they fall according to you?

Comment: yes. in that second codepen they fall in alaska.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple typo:

```
s.addFeatures(f);
```

Should be

```
s.addFeatures([f]);
```

As you only created a single feature.